# Reading environment/shell variables

Tags: python, shell, environment-variables, waf

I see that `waf` has reads some shell variables and saves it, in its environment
(https://code.google.com/p/waf/wiki/EnvironmentVariables). But from the Waf Book, 
I am unable to find, as to how I can add some other variable, of my interest
to be read at `configure` time. Do I have to just use Python's `os` library and read
or does `waf` have any other mechanisms to do so ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the advantage of waf it is in Python so you can get the data from anywhere so you can read using Python libraries.

However waf has done the work for you form the [ApiDocs](https://waf.io/apidocs/Configure.html#waflib.Configure.add_os_flags) there is the add_os_flags on a Configure object which reads an OS environment variables into the env dictionary in a Configure object

e.g.

```py
def configure(conf):
    conf.add_os_flags('CFLAGS')
```

I would note that it might be better to have the data in the build and not in external variables and use command line options to the process. The reason for this is to allow the project to be easily moved to another environment and it will work without having to set extra things that might be forgotten. IN other words keep the configuration together in one place and not spread over several places.

Comment: So, I can use `add_os_flags` to get a shell var.  BTW, I already have a `--<opt>` which is added for this purpose, I wanted to also give the flexibility/choice to pick the shell variable, if the `--<opt>` is missed out at `configure` time.